# Login form now ends in a 505

Tags: php, ini, internals

I could need some help figuring this one out.
This code has worked perfectly fine before, but now all of a sudden it results in a 505 internal error. I belive there is something regarding a forced upgrade on the PHP version from the host.

Does anyone see any sudden mistakes in the code that leads to the error?

got this login form:

```
<?php
    $Returned = false;
    if (isset($_REQUEST['action'])) {
        if ($_REQUEST['action'] == 'returned') $Returned = true;
    }
    if ($Returned) {
        if (isset($_SESSION['LogUsernameExists'])) {
            echo 'Login failed - the password you typed is not correct.';
        } else {
            echo 'Login failed - the username could not be found.';
        }
        // When failed we just send the user back to the frontpage for now
        $RedirectURL = "/";
    } else {
    }
?>

<div class="maincontainer popupText">
    <form action="login_verify.php" method="post">
    Brukernavn:<br>
    <input type="text" name="username" size=30><br>
    Passord:<br>
    <input type="password" name="password" size="30"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="rememberme" value="on">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Logg inn">
    </form>
</div>
```

and this verify form:

```
<?php
    // Turn on output buffering     
    ob_start();

    /* Connecting, selecting database */
    $link = mysql_connect ("localhost", "radiostyrt_hjem", "********") or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db ("radiostyrt_hjem"); 

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    /* Performing SQL query */
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users where Username = '$username'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed");

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

        if ($password == $row['Password']) {
            // Set session variables
            $_SESSION['UserID'] = $row['userID'];
            $_SESSION['Username'] = $row['Username'];
            // Set cookie based on "Remember me" setting
            if (isset($_POST['rememberme'])) {
                if ($_POST['rememberme'] == "on") {
                    setcookie("UserID", $row['userID'], time()+(60*60*24*365));
                    setcookie("Username", $row['Username'], time()+(60*60*24*365));
                    setcookie("Password", $row['Password'], time()+(60*60*24*365));
                }
            }
            $success = 1;
            unset($_SESSION['LogUsernameExists']);
        } else {
            $success = 0;
            $_SESSION['LogUsernameExists'] = true;
        }
    } else {
        $success = 0;
        unset($_SESSION['LogUsernameExists']);
    }
    /* Free resultset */
    mysql_free_result($result);

    /* Closing connection */
    mysql_close($link);

    if ($success == 0) {
        $_SESSION['LogUsername'] = $username;
        header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/login.php?action=returned");
    } else {
        // Flush output buffer  
        ob_end_clean();
        print '<html><body onLoad="javascript:opener.location.reload();window.close();"></body></html>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: please remove change your database credentials immediatly, since you put them in this post.

Comment: Not a big problem, just a test site anyway=) but accepted the change! now help me with my problem:D

Comment: Are you sure it is a **505**, and not a **500**? Since code 505 is named "HTTP Version not supported", which seems highly unlikely on a shared host.

Comment: That is correct my friend. went a little fast. it is a 500 error

Comment: Do you have access to the logs which might contain information about the error? Also, from which to which version did your host upgrade?

Comment: no logs. Asked the ISP but no answer yet. also asked about the php version, but as for now that is unclear

Comment: You can get the Version yourself. Create an PHP-file with exactly one function call in it: `phpinfo();` Then call it from a browser and check the version

Comment: PHP Version 7.2.15

Comment: And which one was it before the upgrade?

Comment: is this still relevant?